# Importing Data into a Table in Supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

Is it possible to import data into a table in supabase?

For example if I have either a csv file or a json file -- can I import that data into a table via the backend of supabase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Supabase dashboard:

1. Go to table editor
2. Create new table
3. Click on Import data via spreadsheet button:
   [image]

Keep in mind that you can only import data from a spreadsheet upon initial table creation.

Comment: I don't see that button -- could it be because I have already created my table and added a couple of test rows of data?  I.e., is it only possible to import data from a spreadsheet upon initial creation of the table?

Comment: That's correct, it's only possible upon initial table creation.

Comment: Okay - thanks.  Perhaps add that to your answer and then I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Works fine for CSV. Json or xlsx doesn't seem to be an option.